# Emgu AccessViolationException randomly occurring after upgrading from Emgu 2 to Emgu 3.1.0.1

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

I was using Emgu 2 (the one using opencv 2.4.10.1) and that was running pretty stable and would run without crashing. I have now upgrade to Emgu 3.1.0.1 and my app will crash sometimes within hours or a day with an AccessViolationException. I have seen it crash at two different locations now. See the two locations marked in the source code below (CRASH1 & CRASH2). So I think there is something fundamentally wrong here.

I am running a Release version of the software. Any one got any ideas what might be going on here?

The CRASH1 exception is:

```
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.AccessViolationException
   at Emgu.CV.CvInvoke.cveSubtract(IntPtr, IntPtr, IntPtr, IntPtr, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.DepthType)
   at Emgu.CV.CvInvoke.Subtract(Emgu.CV.IInputArray, Emgu.CV.IInputArray, Emgu.CV.IOutputArray, Emgu.CV.IInputArray, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.DepthType)
   at Emgu.CV.RotationMatrix2D.CreateRotationMatrix(System.Drawing.PointF, Double, System.Drawing.Size, System.Drawing.Size ByRef)
   at Emgu.CV.Image`2[[Emgu.CV.Structure.Bgr, Emgu.CV.World, Version=3.1.0.2282, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7281126722ab4438],[System.Byte, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].Rotate(Double, System.Drawing.PointF, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.Inter, Emgu.CV.Structure.Bgr, Boolean)
   at Emgu.CV.Image`2[[Emgu.CV.Structure.Bgr, Emgu.CV.World, Version=3.1.0.2282, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7281126722ab4438],[System.Byte, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].Rotate(Double, Emgu.CV.Structure.Bgr, Boolean)
   at XXXX.ProcessFrames()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

The CRASH2 exception is:

```
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.AccessViolationException
   at Emgu.CV.Util.VectorOfMat.VectorOfMatPush(IntPtr, IntPtr)
   at Emgu.CV.Util.VectorOfMat..ctor(Emgu.CV.Mat[])
   at XXXX.ProcessFrames()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

The source code is:

```
    public void start()
    {
        started = true;
        // start processing camera frames
        cameraThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ProcessFrames));
        cameraThread.IsBackground = true;
        cameraThread.Start();
    }

    private void ProcessFrames()
    {
        Bgr frameBg = new Bgr(0,0,0);
        while (true)
        {
            // try to open the camera device
            if (capture == null)
            {
                try
                {
                    int index;
                    bool isNumeric = int.TryParse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CameraSource"], out index);
                    capture = isNumeric ? new Capture(index) : new Capture(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CameraSource"]);
                    capture.SetCaptureProperty(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CapProp.FrameWidth, 640);
                    capture.SetCaptureProperty(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CapProp.FrameHeight, 480);
                    capture.SetCaptureProperty(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CapProp.FourCC, Emgu.CV.VideoWriter.Fourcc('M', 'J', 'P', 'G'));
                }
                catch
                {
                    frameObservers.ForEach(a => a.frame(cameraNotConnectedBitmap, new List<Person>(), recognizer.isActive()));
                }
                Task.Delay(1000).Wait();
                continue;
            }

            // read a frame from the camera
            Mat matFrame = capture.QueryFrame();
            Image<Bgr, byte> frame = null;
            if (matFrame != null)
            {
                frame = matFrame.ToImage<Bgr, byte>();
            }
            if (frame == null)
            {
                frameObservers.ForEach(a => a.frame(cameraNotConnectedBitmap, new List<Person>(), recognizer.isActive()));
                capture = null; // force to reconnect to camera again
                Task.Delay(1000).Wait();
                continue;
            }

            try
            {
                CRASH1 >>>frame = frame.Rotate(Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CameraRotation"]), frameBg, false);
                double scale = Convert.ToDouble(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CameraScale"]);
                if (scale > 0)
                {
                    frame = frame.Resize(scale, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.Inter.Linear);
                }

                Global.FRAME_HEIGHT = frame.Height;
                Global.FRAME_WIDTH = frame.Width;
                rawCameraFeedFrameObservers.ForEach(a => a.frame(frame));

                if (autoBrightness)
                {
                    Image<Lab, Byte> lab = frame.Convert<Lab, Byte>();
                    Image<Gray, Byte>[] planes = lab.Split();
                    CvInvoke.CLAHE(planes[0], claheClipLimit, new Size(8, 8), planes[0]);
                    CRASH2 >>>VectorOfMat vm = new VectorOfMat(planes[0].Mat, planes[1].Mat, planes[2].Mat); 
                    CvInvoke.Merge(vm, lab);
                    frame = lab.Convert<Bgr, Byte>();
                } 
            }
            catch
            {
                // not the end of the world
                Log.INFO("INFO", "Processing the frame failed, skipping this frame");
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: this looks like one thread of a bigger application, your problem is likely elsewhere and is probably related to some kind of race condition or other mishandling of unmanaged data, that simply did not manifest itself with previous library version

Comment: The thread basically grabs a frame from the camera, processes it as seen in the code then posts it to the UI thread, which makes a bitmap of the frame and displays it on the screen. The code in the UI thread does not manipulate the frame in anyway. So I cannot see how it would create an access violation.

Comment: I recommend do dispose every disposables (ie. Mat) I had accessviolation issues on my EMGU tries (especially with BOW related calls.) I've started using OpenCVSharp, everyhing is more stable now. But latest version has some serios issues I use: https://www.nuget.org/packages/OpenCvSharp3-AnyCPU/3.2.0.20170324

Comment: you mean explicitly do frame.Dispose() at the end? Won't there be an issue as I have to post to the UI thread to display the frame it will then be disposed by the camera thread.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe one thread would access system device while the initialisation is done by another concurrent thread...

As both Crash1 & Crash2 exception show this line

```
at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Did you try to catch exception directly on `cameraThread.Start()` ?

```
public void start()
{
    started = true;
    // start processing camera frames
    cameraThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ProcessFrames));
    cameraThread.IsBackground = true;
    try
    {
       cameraThread.Start();
    }
    catch
    {
       started = false;
       /* HERE ACCESS VIOLATION APPEAR, SO DELAY  */
       Task.Delay(1000).Wait();
       /* AND RETRY  */
    }
    continue;
}
```